# Change the default layout and properties of Powershell in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-8.1

I want to change the default layout of Window's Powershell so that it can expand to entire screen.

I tried from properties option.

But when I click the ok button, I am getting below error in Windows 8.1

> Unable to modify the shortcut:
>   Check to make sure it has not been deleted or renamed

Settings get reflected even getting the above error, but it reset to its original settings after reopening of Powershell.

Comment: Why don't you just make you own shortcut and edit the properties of that one?

Comment: How to do that? Can you please help me out of that?

Answer (score 2):

Edit the "Defaults" which is in the menu above "Properties". This will persist your changes even after closing and re-opening the window.

Comment: I have done this, but it is not working. The value I put got saved but its open with original settings.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at setting up your Powershell profile. The profile file is usually kept in your user location and contains, amongst other things, the settings for your Powershell session.

This should get you started: http://www.howtogeek.com/50236/customizing-your-powershell-profile/

And there's plenty of reading here on SO if you search for 'Powershell Profile'.